# How to forgive/overcome from the pain of accidentally killing a parrot

Tags: scripture, paap

I have never had any pet. I don't keep them because it hurts when they leave you :(. But, the day before yesterday , an orphaned parrot came to my home randomly. I loved it, so I kept it with me in a small cage. I don't have any experience of how to take care/manage pet. I was feeling ,it's very dirty and cleaning it's body all the time. So, next day(today) - I thought to give it a shower, so that it can be cleaned. I gave him a good shower in wash basin and then allowed him to get dry.

But, instead of getting dried , I started feeling like ,it's getting sick. My mom came , and started asking what did you do to it .. it's not able to even walk now.. it will not survive.. I was thinking it will get dried and start flying again, but  it's condition was getting worse.. I also started feeling ,that may be it will not survive .. :( :( :( :(.. I started to get it dried with dryer .. but even after getting dried his condition wasn't improving.. There's no bird doctor here nearby .. I couldn't imagine getting died in my hands.. so I took him to nearby hanuman temple with me and left him there and come back :( :(..

Now, I feel it's all my mistake .. the bird was coincidently very nice with me, even I keep it out from cage ,it fly and sit on my table ,my hand and my shoulders .. that's why I thought to adapt it.. it never try to fly out when it's with me.. like it knows me since years ..in a day, it became that comfortable ,that was also really weird but good ..and it got killed because of me :(..

anyway in our religion to पश्चताप this पाप happened because of me ..and forgive myself and move on :(

Comment: You did what you thought was best, whatever may be the result so no need carrying undue guilt.

Comment: @Narasimham I don't agree with that